# Openssl cert not accepted on cisco load balancer

Tags: openssl, certificate

Been fighting a expired cert issue for the past few days.
I am updating a cisco ace load balancer with an updated cert.
However every time I attempt to validate the cert it is not valid or does not match.
Steps I have used:

- Log into web server with valid cert installed Go to IIS Manager
- Create Certificate request in server certificates Edit correct
  information for company location etc. RSA and 2048 and save as a
  cert.csr
- Once *.csr is created
- open in notepad to get server request
  info.
- Go to: microsoft web certsvr address to create AD cert.
- Request new cert.
- Advanced and add the info copied from notepad into the appropriate
  field.
- click next and download the cert.cer
- Install the cert.cer into
  the cert store (personal)
- Open MMC on the same server and move the
  cert from personal to trusted root. (shows the key and cert as
  valid.)
- Edit the newly created cert.cer file with: Openssl openssl
  x509 -inform der -in certs\cert.cer -out certs\certs.cer.pem
- Export the PFX from the trusted root store.  Create cert.pfx placed
  in the same folder that cert.cer and cert.cer.pem is located.
- get the certificate only and not the private key from a PFX file.
- Run the following command to export the private key: openssl pkcs12 -in certs\cert.pfx -nocerts -out certs\cert.key.pem -nodes
- Run the following command to remove the passphrase from the private key: openssl rsa -in certs\cert.key.pem -out certs\cert.server.key

  *Just for fun I also do the following to allow for compatibility: //
  Convert without requiring a password for the private key and include
  the private key in the cert. openssl pkcs12 -in Certs\cert.pfx -out
  certs\certs_nokey.pem -nodes

Any help or suggestions would be deeply appreciated.

*UPDATE* the CA is Microsoft certificate services. This would be a DHCP server giving out certs for the connecting servers. Affectionately (CertServ CA)
**UPDATE*** This actually worked with the cisco load balancer as well as the Servers under it. Thanks.

Comment: `Log into web server with valid cert installed - Create Certificate request` - I am confused about what you are trying to do here. Can you update your question to describe what you actually need instead of just a simple description of steps. Did you already request the certificate you wanted from the web server, and get it issued from a public CA, and now you are trying to export, or are you trying to generate a completely new cert from an internal CA?  It looks like you have tried to mix-and-match three different sets of instructions for completely separate tasks.  I am very confused.